# Replace a Const with a dialogue box to update range?

Tags: vba

I have a worksheet that I use to place raw data in order to validate data on individual files I cut up from that raw data. Thing is, the script tends to truncate the data it validates and disregards blank rows at the tail end of the rows I bring over.

How can I change this:

```
Private Const numCols As Long = 76
```

to do a `columns.count`?

for example: if there are 76 columns, but row two has data until 50 columns, it will take that row and transpose it without those tailing blank cells from columns 51-76, offsetting my data and returning `FALSE` values when I validate. Now I have to update that `long` variable to make sure it doesn't cut off trailing blanks when my dataset changes.

What can I do to make it more dynamic, but also make sure the script doesn't ignore blanks when I need them included as well?

Comment: How do you know how many trailing blanks you have?

Comment: @TimWilliams That I do not know because each row will have a different amount. Some rows may have all 76 columns filled with values, some may stop sooner and some later on in the range. Really, I want the `Const` to refer to how many headers there are, that way it will always know how far to reach when there are varying degrees of trailing blanks in the row.

Comment: @TimWilliams even if I could get a Msg Box for the user to input that would be better than having them go into the VBA Editor to do so and potentially mess up code

Comment: Are the headers always on row1?  If so then the last column is `sheet1.cells(1, columns.count).end(xltoleft).column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your header determines how many columns, then you could count that row to get the number. Assume your header is in row 1.

```
Dim numCols as Long
numCols = Application.WorksheetFunction.Counta(sheet1.rows(1))
```

You could also get it from the user

```
numCols = Application.InputBox("Enter # of columns")
```

If you're using the number of columns in a few procedures, you can either pass it as an argument or use a module-level variable. Declare a module level variable at the top of the module (in the declarations section, before any Sub or Function statements) like

```
Private numCols As Long
```

You'll still need to set it in the first procedure you run. It can't be a constant because it changes depending on the width of the first row.

You can do the same with a reference to the worksheet. I used the sheet's codename (the name that the user can't see and can't change), but you could create a variable to refer to the sheet

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")
```

I generally use a codename rather than a variable, but it's a personal preference.

Comment: Hey, just ran into an error with the `sheet1` part of your first solution. It says variable not defined, but even when I do, it throws an object-oriented error my way. Any way around that?

Comment: `sheet1` is standing in for your actual worksheet reference.  You need to declare and set something...

Comment: @TimWilliams is there a way to make this a private constant so I don't have to include these variables in every private function in the script?

Comment: If it's always the same sheet then I would just use the sheet's codename (as seen in the VBA editor project explorer) in your VBA